How to install modules into Blender's Python
I have a Python file that is hundreds of lines long. To make things simpler and to cut down on scrolling, I want to put the functions, e.g.
def addNumbers(a, b):
    print("Sum is ", a + b)

in an external file e.g.
(‘larder.py’) 

and then import the module
from larder import *

and call the function using
# call function
addNumbers(2, 5)
multiplyNumbers(5, 4)

But this will only work in Blender if I put my module ('larder.py') into Blender's Python. Is there a way to do this (on a Mac)???
This:
Installing module to blender's python (Mac)
Didn't do it.

watch this: https://youtu.be/2zGIERHU2mk this works definetely on Mac. On Windows it might have to be changed a bit.

Thanks @Chris
I started there. I replaced
installModule("pandas")
with
installModule('path_to_my_file/myfile.py')
and I also tried
installModule(path_to_my_file/myfile.py)
